# Where to define Dependency Properties in UserControl developed in MVVM style?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

What part of MVVM should contain dependency properties? If I put them into ViewModel then how user will set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in your CustomControls / UserControls.